# Answers without upvotes are still in random order when one of the answers is deleted

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, sorting

Answers with zero votes posted shortly after each other have a randomized order to give them an equal exposure, and to prevent the [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) effect.

However, when one of the answers is deleted, the users that can see deleted answers (marked by a red background) still get a random order. Should not existing answers have priority over deleted answers?

Example of a case where a user sees the deleted answer on top:

I have tried to refresh the page, but it still randomizes the order. Example case: [How to spell buggz](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/how-to-spell-buggz) (temporary, before the existing answer get an upvote.)

[image]

Comment: Should be fine after refresh, you probably clicked the banner saying that new answer has been posted, right?

Comment: @ShadowWizard  Nope, it still sometimes end up on top after refreshing.

Comment: So this is caching, as the sorted list is being cached for a short while (e.g. minute) and doesn't detect the answer was deleted

Comment: @ShadowWizard Does 30 minutes count as "a few minutes"?

Comment: So it means you're sorting by "active" and not by "votes", and that bug is already reported.